# How to make Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown work under a list item

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I have a structure as -

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.pull-right
            ul.nav.navbar-nav
                li.active
                    a(href="/") Home
                li
                    a About
                li
                    a Contact
                li
                    div(ng-include="'/partials/account/navbar-login'",ng-controller="navBarLoginController")
```

the navbar-login partial file has the content as -

```
form.navbar-form(ng-hide="identity.isAuthenticated()")
    .form-group.login
        input.form-control(placeholder="Email", ng-model="username")
    .form-group.login
        input.form-control(placeholder="Password",type="password",ng-model="password")
    button.btn.btn-primary.login(ng-click="signin(username,password)") Login
ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right(ng-show="identity.isAuthenticated()")
    li.dropdown
        a.dropdown-toggle(href="", data-toggle="dropdown")
            | {{identity.currentUser.firstName + " " + identity.currentUser.lastName}}
            b.caret
        ul.dropdown-menu
            li
                a(href="", ng-click="signout()") Sign Out
```

Now when i try to run this after including the bootstrap.js, dropdown.js, bootstrap.css my dropdown box is not working. I guess because it is inside a list element in the header. So, how can i improve it?

Comment: Is there a reason you did not include the opening/closing tags. IE: <div class".navbar etc...

Comment: Yeah, This is the jade syntax. It allows you to write your markup without having to define all the extra things like opening/closing tags and much more. Give it a try, saves a lot of time